# Android ActionBar error

Tags: android-activity, android-actionbar, themes

```
 package mavilla.paavaiinstitutions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    int mPosition = -1;
    String mTitle = "";

    // Array of strings storing country names
    String[] mCountries ;

    // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
    int[] mFlags = new int[]{
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.about,
            R.drawable.ins,
            R.drawable.campus,
            R.drawable.compass,
            R.drawable.gallery,
            R.drawable.cap,
            R.drawable.alumini,
            R.drawable.tieup,
            R.drawable.contact
    };

    // Array of strings to initial counts
    String[] mCount = new String[]{
            "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "" };

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private LinearLayout mDrawer ;
    private List<HashMap<String,String>> mList ;
    private SimpleAdapter mAdapter;
    final private String COUNTRY = "country";
    final private String FLAG = "flag";
    final private String COUNT = "count";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Getting an array of country names
        mCountries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries);

        // Title of the activity
        mTitle = (String)getTitle();

        // Getting a reference to the drawer listview
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

        // Getting a reference to the sidebar drawer ( Title + ListView )
        mDrawer = ( LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        // Each row in the list stores country name, count and flag
        mList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hm.put(COUNTRY, mCountries[i]);
            hm.put(COUNT, mCount[i]);
            hm.put(FLAG, Integer.toString(mFlags[i]) );
            mList.add(hm);
        }

// Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { FLAG,COUNTRY,COUNT };

// Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.flag , R.id.country , R.id.count};

// Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.drawer_layout defines the layout of each item
        mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mList, R.layout.drawer_layout, from, to);

        // Getting reference to DrawerLayout
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // Creating a ToggleButton for NavigationDrawer with drawer event listener
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer , R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){

            /** Called when drawer is closed */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                highlightSelectedCountry();
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            /** Called when a drawer is opened */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Select a Country");
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        // Setting event listener for the drawer
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        // ItemClick event handler for the drawer items
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                    long arg3) {

                // Increment hit count of the drawer list item
                incrementHitCount(position);

                if(position < 5) { // Show fragment for countries : 0 to 4
                    showFragment(position);
                }else{ // Show message box for countries : 5 to 9
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mCountries[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                // Closing the drawer
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawer);
            }
        });

        // Enabling Up navigation
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

// Setting the adapter to the listView
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void incrementHitCount(int position){
        HashMap<String, String> item = mList.get(position);
        String count = item.get(COUNT);
        item.remove(COUNT);
        if(count.equals("")){
            count = " 1 ";
        }else{
            int cnt = Integer.parseInt(count.trim());
            cnt ++;
            count = " " + cnt + " ";
        }
        item.put(COUNT, count);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void showFragment(int position){

        //Currently selected country
        mTitle = mCountries[position];

// Creating a fragment object
        CountryFragment cFragment = new CountryFragment();

// Creating a Bundle object
        Bundle data = new Bundle();

// Setting the index of the currently selected item of mDrawerList
        data.putInt("position", position);

// Setting the position to the fragment
        cFragment.setArguments(data);

// Getting reference to the FragmentManager
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

// Creating a fragment transaction
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

// Adding a fragment to the fragment transaction
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, cFragment);

// Committing the transaction
        ft.commit();
    }

    // Highlight the selected country : 0 to 4
    public void highlightSelectedCountry(){
        int selectedItem = mDrawerList.getCheckedItemPosition();

        if(selectedItem > 4)
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(mPosition, true);
        else
            mPosition = selectedItem;

        if(mPosition!=-1)
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mCountries[mPosition]);
    }
}
```

i have extended Main Activity from Activity as shown to apply custom theme. 
But I'm getting error below in `actionBar` code:

```
getSupportActionBar()
```

// Enabling Up navigation
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

```
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Please help me as i am very new in stackoverflow and android..thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you setting your action bar? That should be done in **onCreate()** method. You should read some tutorials/training on official Android developer website.

Comment: sorry but actually thats a long code. i just posted the error i got on extending mainactivity from activity instead of ActionBarActivity. i have created actionbar in OnCreate() only

Comment: Oh OK. If you are using ActionBarActivity than you should call **getSupportActionBar()**, otherwise if you are using Activity, you should call **getActionBar()**.

Comment: Thank u very much. that fixed the error :) but getting error in supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); getSupportFragmentManager(); sorry to ask again..

Comment: Instead of **supportInvalidateOptionsMenu** you should call **invalidateOptionsMenu** and instead of **getSupportFragmentManager** you should call **getFragmentManager**. You are using the default Activity now, not the **support** one!

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. i have cleared all the errors but even if i change getSupportFragmentManager to get FragmentManager i am full error in FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); only error in my module :( please help

Comment: Probably instead of **import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;** you have to import this FragmentManager **import android.app.FragmentManager;**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are no longer using the support **ActionBarActivity**, but the normal Android **Activity**.

Thats why instead of

- **getSupportActionBar()** you have to call **getActionBar()**
- **supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()** you have to call **invalidateOptionsMenu()**
- **getSupportFragmentManager()** you have to call **getFragmentManager()**

and so on..